# RAID0 setup on Asus M5A97

Tags: ubuntu, usb, raid

I just erased two WD Blue 250Gb and I want to setup them up in RAID0 to speed up I/O throughput.

I am using an Asus Motherboard model M5A97 R2.0.
I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop on this RAID0 using a USB stick created as ISO with Rufus.

Now, whenever I try to setup RAID, I loose USB booting option.

Here is what I have done so far:

In BIOS:
- Advanced Mode:
 --> Advanced/SATA Configuration/SATA Ports 1 - 4     = RAID
 --> Advanced/SATA Configuration/SATA Ports 5 - 6     = RAID
 --> Advanced/SATA Configuration/Board SATA RAID ROM  = Legacy ROM
- Save and Reboot
- CTRL+F to enter RAID Menu
 --> Setup my two WD250 in array#1
 --> Save, plug Ubuntu Live USB dongle in USB port and reboot
- I get error reading disk and the USB stick is not flashing at all.
- When I go into BISO, I can't see the USB stick anymore.
- I undo everything, reboot, and ther I can access the USB stick again.

Something I'm not doing right or I might not have the right tools for that.

Comment: Ok, I accidentally managed to boot from the USB stick.  I set my SATA ports to RAID, then I used Boot override option from the Boot Menu in BIOS.  Then I could Start the installation and use my RAID array as Install location.  But now I'm stuck at grub failing to install to dev/sda.  I searched a bit and found this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/43036/how-do-i-install-grub-on-a-raid-system-installation  I'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to get the USB stick to work again.

First I had to shutdown the PC.
Then disconnect the hard drives from SATA Ports.
With the USB stick in, boot.

And tadaa! USB stick is alive again.

Now, shutdown, reconnect the drives and I coudl boot from USB anytime.

I still don't know why it stopped working in the first place.